# Forwarding DragEvent and MouseEvent in QML (possible bug?)

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I want to declare an `Item`
that has a few `MouseArea`s and `DropArea`s as children. An example has just one of each:

```
import QtQuick 2.7

Item {
    id: root
    signal clicked(int someValue, QtObject mouse) // MouseEvent fails
    signal entered(int someValue, QtObject drag) // DragEvent fails
    MouseArea {
        id: mArea
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            console.log(mouse) // Tells me: QQuickMouseEvent(0x...)
            root.clicked(5, mouse)
        }
    }
    DropArea {
        id: dArea
        anchors.fill: parent
        keys: ['exampleKey']
        onEntered: {
            console.log(drag) // Tells me:QQuickDropEvent(0x...)
            root.entered(12, drag)
        }
    }
}
```

I want to forward the events, but add some more information to it, so I trigger handle the signals and trigger new, exposed signals.
The only thing I fail, is to forward the [`MouseEvent`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-mouseevent.html), respectively the [`DragEvent`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-dragevent.html), which acording to the documentation should be types after importing `QtQuick 2.7` (as I did). But I guess they are the relevant Objects, as the `console.log(mouse)` tells me it is a `QQuickMouseEvent`.

QML tells me:

> Invalid signal parameter type: MouseEvent

I guess the solution is trivial, but I can't find it documented anywhere. It's not even documented if there is a baseclass I could use in their stead.

**EDIT: The/A baseclass is QtObject. But the documentation fails. Is this a bug? Or am I wrong?**

Comment: Did you try replacing `QtObject` by the generic basic type`var` in your signals  (`signal clicked(int someValue, var mouse)`)?

Comment: I found out by now, that the QtObject works. What does not work, is to use the specific signal types. So I won't have code completion, e.g. What surprises me, is that you might think, from the documentation, that once you imported `QtQuick 2.7` the EventTypes should be to your avail. And that the documentation fails to mention that they indeed inherit something, especially a `QtObject`.